# Simple OS X app with WKWebView viewer

Tags: webview, swift, wkwebview

I’m trying to create simple OS X app (not iOS) with a web viewer using the new `WKWebView` and the Swift language. I’m hoping to take advantage of the faster performance of the `WKWebView` class.

In the projects AppDelegate.swift file I have the following code:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet var containerView : NSView! = nil

    var webView: WKWebView?

    var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req)

}
```

In the MainMenu.xib file I have added a Custom View object to the main window and linked it to the `@IBOutlet var containerView`.

I’m getting error messages on the last two lines of code:

`var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)`

> ‘AppDelegate. Type’ does not have a member named ‘url’

`self.webView!.loadRequest(req)`

> Expected declaration

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This took me a while to figure out.

```
import Cocoa
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    var viewController : ViewController!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        self.viewController = ViewController(nibName:"ViewController", bundle:nil)
        self.window.contentView = self.viewController!.view
        self.window.contentViewController = self.viewController!
        self.viewController!.view.frame = self.window.contentView.bounds;
    }

    ...
}
```

This essentially replaces whatever is in my `NSWindow` with the view and view controller of my own making. My implementation of the `ViewController` class looks like this:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!

        var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    } 
}
```

So essentially what happens is that I create a custom view controller that sets the `WKWebView` as its view, and then I set it and its view to the `NSWindow` view controller and view.

Answer (score 1):

Move the last three lines (declaring `url`, `req` and loading the request) into a method on AppDelegate, like `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` (similar to what @MinnesotaSteve's answer suggests). You cannot have top-level statements like that.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I've wrapped the three line into a method as suggested and I no longer get code errors. Great! However when I run the app I getting a blank grey window. The web view is not loading any pages. I've checked the Custom View object and it is connected to the @IBoutlet var ContainerView. Am i missing something?

Comment: Yes you are. At no point are you actually displaying your web view. Your container view doesn't contain anything. Either add your web view to your container view using code (using addSubview) or put your web view in using interface builder and point an IBOutlet to it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and see if it is useful as a starting point:

import UIKit
import WebKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView?
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url = NSURL(string:"http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=AAPL&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=s&p=m50,m200")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried this and it works great for iOS but not for Mac OSX my attempt above was to try and adapt this to work for OS X.

Comment: Isn't UIViewController specific to iOS instead of OSX?